# Create html button/label with text and zero initial width

Tags: html, css, width, dart

I'm trying to create html buttons/labels with text and initially zero width (after insertion, they'll be stretched to be visible, but I want this transition to be smooth). I've tried modifying the initial width and min-width style properties, but no luck.

The following is what I want to work.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <style type="text/css">
      .zerowidth{width: 0px;min-width: 0px;}
      .nonzerowidth{font-size: 30px;}
      button{font-size: 30px;}
      label{font-size: 30px;}
      span{font-size: 0px;}
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <span>
      <button>This should be visible</button>
      <button class='zerowidth'>I want this to be invisible</button>
      <label class='zerowidth'>same here</label>
      <button>c</button>
    </span>
  </body>
</html>
```

I want the above to appear identical to a version without the .zerowidth elements, such that the .zerowidth elements can have their widths animated to nonzero values later.

If there's an easier way to insert an item into the DOM that allows for smooth repositioning of the elements around it (the above is a toy example - in practice I'll be inserting elements programatically from Dart), I'd be happy to hear that too (though I'd rather stay away from absolutely positioning everything if possible).

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To make a `button` element really zero-width as regards to total width occupied (not just content width, which is what the CSS property `width` specifies), you need to set horizontal padding and vertical borders to zero. Moreover, to prevent browsers from dividing the content into several lines, you need to prevent line breaks. And you need to make overflowing content hidden; for an element with zero content width, any content overflows, of course. You would thus add the following:

```
  .zerowidth {
     padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;
     border-left-width: 0; border-right-width: 0;
     white-space: nowrap;
     overflow: hidden;
  }
```

For some reason, this is not sufficient for making a `label` element zero-width (tested on IE, Chrome, Firefox). On the other hand, a `label` element is for specifying labels of form fields and other labellable elements, and you get nothing but trouble by trying to use it for other content. So consider using e.g. `span` instead.

Comment: Urgh, so obvious. Works a charm. Thanks

Comment: Omg - I can't believe I have forgotten this... thank you so much! Finally able to fix that button transition (sadly, `display` attribute cannot be animated).

Answer (score 1):

```
<button class='zerowidth'>I want this to be invisible</button>
<label class='zerowidth'>same here</label>
```

if you want these two things invisible, why not add `style="display:none;"` to both. And if you want to display them, do a `hover effect` and `display:block;` to that element.

Comment: I want the content to be viewable shortly after insertion, but I don't want its insertion/visibility to cause other elements on the DOM to 'jump' to their new location.

Thanks anyway